# Handling Exception in Perl

Tags: perl, ftp

I am new to perl, and I have created a perl script for ftp file transfer.

But if the `$ftp->login` is unsuccessful, program gets terminated with the following error message:

```
Uncaught exception from user code:
        Cannot login Login incorrect.
 at ftp.sender.com line 89
```

Code fragment from the program:

```
$ftp->login($config->[$i]->{'USERNAME'},$config->[$i]->{'PSWD'}) or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
```

Is there any way to handle this exception / unsuccessful login, so that program will not terminate?

Comment: well keyword "die" terminates the program. replace "die" with something you want the program to do... like $ftp->login($config->[$i]->{'USERNAME'},$config->[$i]->{'PSWD'}) or print "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;

Comment: See [Try::Tiny](http://p3rl.org/Try::Tiny) for advanced exception handling.

Comment: Thanks! that worked

Comment: Also which is the best way to identify whether the login was successful? I got $ftp->code = 230, and $ftp->status =2 upon successful login. Can we validate in that way? Is $ftp->status means success?

Comment: If the login does not return a false value it was successful. That's what the `or` does. If it returns `undef` or `0` (I don't know which one it is), it will call the RHS of the `or`.

Comment: @simbabque
Thanks for your response. So is that possible to have multiple statements in or? Because I have to print an error message and exit from the loop if the login is unsuccessful. I have tried to write compound statement, but it seems to be not working.

Comment: Please state what module you are using. Also, there isn't much that your program can usefully do unless the FTP session is logged in. I think a fatal exception is appropriate here

Comment: `$ftp->login(@{ $config->[$i] }{qw/ USERNAME PSWD /}) or warn "Cannot login";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several different ways to do stuff only if the login worked.

- Let the whole program `die`

  You already know that one. The whole program stops if the login fails. It works because `login` returns a true value on success, and a false value on failure. So if `undef` gets returend, the RHS of the `or` is called, which is `die`.

  ```
  $ftp->login($user, $pw) or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
  ```
- Use a `do` block

  If you want to stick with the `or`, you can use a `do { ... }` block to group several statements. This is weird.

  ```
  $ftp->login($user, $pw) or do { 
      stuff();
      more_stuff();
  };
  ```
- Check the return value of `login`

  If you put your `login` in an `if`, you can call as much code as you want.

  ```
  if ( $ftp->login($user, $pw) ) {
       stuff();
       more_stuff();
  }
  ```
- Put all of it in a sub and let the `login` return

  Group all the FTP things into one sub and call that. Then return from the sub if one of the steps fail. To get the error message you could return the `ftp` object and check the ultimate success outside.

  ```
  sub ftp_stuff {
      my ($foo) = @_;
      $ftp->login($user, $pw) or return $ftp;
      $ftp->stuff($foo) or return $ftp;

      return $ftp;
  }

  # and somewhere else
  my $ftp = ftp_stuff($bar);
  die "Something went wrong: ", $ftp->message if $ftp->message;
  ```
- Use `die` or Exceptions and [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny)

  The nices approach is to use Try::Tiny.

  ```
  use Try::Tiny;

  try {
      $ftp->login($user, $pw) or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
      stuff() or die "stuff ", $ftp->message;
      # ...
  } catch {
      # exception/error is in $_
      warn "Could not log in" if /Cannot login/;
      # ...
  };

  # continue with your program
  ```

  An alternative to Try::Tiny is [an `eval` block](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

  ```
  eval {
      $ftp->login($user, $pw) or die "Cannot login ", $ftp->message;
      stuff() or die "stuff ", $ftp->message;
      # ...
  };
  if ($@) {
      # exception/error is in $@
      warn "Could not log in" if $@ =~ /Cannot login/;
      # ...
  };
  ```